# Scala, iterating a collection, working out 10% points

Tags: scala

While iterating an arbitrarily-sized List, I'd like to print some output at ~10% intervals to show that the iteration is progressing. For any list of 10 or more elements, I want 10 outputs printed.

I've played around with `%` and `Math` functions, but am not always getting 10 outputs printed unless the list sizes are multiples of 10. Would appreciate your help.

Comment: Please give us what you tried so far, and what error you get (do you have 9 results printed? 11? none at all?) and what you expect on a specific example.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to calculate 10% of the size based on your input, and then use `IterableLike.grouped` to group based on that percent:

```
object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val range = 0 to Math.abs(Random.nextInt(100))

    val length = range.length
    val percent = Math.ceil((10.0 * length) / 100.0).toInt

    println(s"Printing by $percent percent")

    range.grouped(percent).foreach {
      listByPercent =>
        println(s"Printing $percent elements: ")
        listByPercent.foreach(println)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless the length of your list is divisible by `10`, then you are not going to get `10` print statements.  Here I am rounding by interval up (`ceil`) so you will have less print statements.  You could used `Math.floor` which would round down, and give you more print statements.

```
// Some list
val list = List.range(0, 27)

// Find the interval that is roughly 10 percent
val interval = Math.ceil(list.length / 10.0)

// Zip the list with the index, so that we can look at the indexes
list.zipWithIndex.foreach {
  case (value, index) =>

    // If an index is divisible by out interval, do your logging
    if (index % interval == 0) {
      println(s"$index / ${list.length}")
    }

    // Do something with the value here
}
```

Output:

```
0 / 27
3 / 27
6 / 27
9 / 27
12 / 27
15 / 27
18 / 27
21 / 27
24 / 27
```